# Python 2.7.5 .count() being ignored?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to debug some code for someone, and have run into a rather odd scenario. The purpose of the code is to search for duplicates in a given list and then return a list with no duplicates. (Note, the person writing the code chose to simply delete the duplicates from the list, when I personally would just add each value to a new list. However, I am still intrigued by the oddity). The code is as follows:

```
def remove_duplicates(duplicates):
    duplicates_del = duplicates 
    for i in duplicates_del:
        if duplicates_del.count(i) > 1:
            duplicates_del.remove(i)
    return duplicates_del

remove_duplicates([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

When run, the code will return `[3, 3, 3]` and after some debugging, I've found that the code will work fine until `duplicates_del.count(i)` is equal to 4. On the next round, it will completely skip everything inside the for statement and go directly to the return statement, resulting in the answer that we get.

I have learned that changing the if statement to `while duplicates_del.count(i) > 1:` will make the code run flawlessly.

I've looked into the code for the debugger, and learned that there is a breakpoint class that can ignore counts. Is the if statement somehow triggering this breakpoint, or is there another reason why the code doesn't run fully with an if statement instead of a while loop?

Comment: Don't remove elements you are looping through - it's a bad idea. Your function is easily done with `set(duplicates)`. You can fix your code by having the loop through `duplicates` rather than `duplicates_del`

Comment: I know, which is why I prefer add the values to a new list. I'm just curious as to why the code acts the way it does. :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you're iterating over a list while you're removing items. This will mostly always result in unexpected results. Take a look at:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for item in L:
    if item == 1 or item == 2 or item == 3:
        L.remove(item)
print L
```

The output is:

```
[2, 4, 5]
```

Notice that `2` was never removed. If we print `item` in each loop, we get:

```
1
3
5
```

After python removes `1`, the order of the list will change, and `2` won't necessarily be the next item in the loop (in fact, `3` is). Notice how `4` is also skipped.

---

To avoid such behaviour, you must iterate over a copy of the list. Sadly, what you did was not making a copy. Doing `duplicates_del = duplicates` will make both objects reference the same identity, so changing an element in one will change it in the other.

You should do this:

```
def remove_duplicates(duplicates):
    for i in duplicates[:]: # Creates a copy of the list
        if duplicates.count(i) > 1:
            duplicates.remove(i)
    return duplicates
```

Comment: Accidentally hit the wrong button. >.< But yes, Thanks! You'll have a green check as soon as the timer is up. c:

Comment: @GavinFeriancek haha :p

Comment: Let's not forget the simplest solution of using what already exists in Python:
`def remove_duplicates(duplicates): return list(set(duplicates))`

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting from the list as you loop over it.

Usually, this means that the item following one that is deleted is skipped over.

In this case `remove` is removing the first matching element each time, so the entire list is being shifted down. The list iterator doesn't see that the list has changed, so increments to the next item.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's nice to know what actually happens behind the scenes in python. c: